# How do I create a list in of the type [number, number][ ] from values inside a nested dictionary?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am requesting data from a server and it is returning it in the form of a list of dictionaries.

I am only interested in the data inside the `start` which is another dictionary:

[image]

and I want to save that (x,y) data in the `start` as a list in the form `[number, number][]`

here is my code for that:

```html
    getCoordinates = (): [number, number][] => {

        let pathCoordinates: [number,number][] = []

        let path = this.props.coordinates.path //data from the server
       
        let i;

        for (i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
            for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(path[i])) {
                if (key == "start") {
                    pathCoordinates.push([value.x, value.y])
                }
            }
        }
        return pathCoordinates;
    }
```

However, I am receiving error for `([value.x, value.y])` saying 'Object is of type unknown'.
Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add types for path,

```
interface TrackPoint{
  start: {
    x: number;
    y: number;
  }
}
let path: TrackPoint[] = this.props.coordinates.path as TrackPoint[]  //data from the server
```

and try to use for of syntax

```
 for(let value of path) {
    let {x, y} = value.start;
    pathCoordinates.push([x, y])
 }
```

Or you can just simply use map.

Answer (score 0):

Simple -

```
    interface TrackPoint {
        cost: number,
        start: {
            x: number;
            y: number;
        },
        end: {
            x: number;
            y: number;
        }
    }

    getCoordinates = (): [number, number][] => {

    const coordinates: TrackPoint[] = this.props.coordinates; 

    return coordinates.map(coordinate => ([coordinate.start.x, coordinate.start.y]));

 
}
```